# python datetime, convert weekday's abbrv to number?

Tags: python, datetime

How would i go about converting a weekday abbreviation (%a) into the weekday number (%u) using python datetime module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import calendar
>>> zip(list(calendar.day_abbr), range(7))
[('Mon', 0), ('Tue', 1), ('Wed', 2), ('Thu', 3), ('Fri', 4), ('Sat', 5), ('Sun', 6)]
```

Comment: No need for `zip` here - `list(calendar.day_abbr).index` will do exactly what the questioner wants.

Comment: @lvc Agreed, `zip` just for visualization.

Answer (score 2):

Better use the time.strptime function, which depends on the locale. If it is set to English (usually by default), you should get

```
>>> import time 
>>> time.strptime("Tue", '%a').tm_wday
>>> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the `datetime` module with an arbitrary date and save the results for the conversions for `%a` and `%u` in a map. `%a` is the key for this map, `%u` is the value.

Increment the date by one day.

Repeat 7 times.

Now you have a map which returns the value you seek for any possible value of `%a`.